# Pandas groupby get count of values greater than 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe which has many weeks data but in this dataframe, i have shown only **one week data**.

In every week, I want the **count of all NEW and DELETED rows count which have value > 0**

[image]

There are **14 NEW** and **13 DELETED** ROWS whose value is > 0

Below is the code i tried from which i am **able to get the NEW count** but i also want DELETED count

```
company = company[company['NEW']>0].groupby(['start_date', 'end_date']).count()
```

Following snippet is **not working when i trying to get both NEW and DELETED count**

```
company = company[company[['NEW','DELETED']]>0].groupby(['start_date', 'end_date']).count()
```

Please suggest me where i am doing wrong.

**Update** :-
Tried the following but NEW and DELETED are both coming as 13 but I wanted NEW and DELETED as 14 and 13

```
company = company[(company['NEW']>0) & (company['DELETED']>0)].groupby(['start_date', 'end_date']).count()
```

Comment: can you add the text from that screen grab

Comment: are you reassigning grouped by dataframe to company ?